# How do I use the lang() selector in Sass?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div to store text excerpts, and the header is applied using the :before selector.

```css
.myDiv{
  &:before {
    content = "My Title";
  }
}
```

I'm storing these excerpts in both an English and a Spanish version - both languages are housed in divs belonging to the same class, and they are differentiated using the lang property.

```html
<div class="myDiv" lang="en">
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv" lang="es">
    <p>¡Hola Mundo!</p>
</div>
```

How would I apply the a different title depending on the language using SASS? I've tried the following:

```css
@mixin divTitles {
  &:lang(en) and &:before{
    content: "My Title";
  }
  
  &:lang(es) and &:before{
    content: "Mi título";
  }
}
```

But it falls over when I try to add the language operator, even though the "[and](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-operators/)" operator is allowed in SASS, and the "[:lang()](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/lang/)" pseudo-selector works in CSS.

**Edit:** I changed it to

```css
@mixin divTitles {
  &:lang(en) {
    &:before{
      content: "My Title";
    }
  }
      
  &:lang(es) { 
    &:before{
      content: "Mi título";
    }
  }
}
```

and it works. Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: I'm wrong or  "and"  operator is just for check conditions so if X and Y are true then .... not to concatenate

Answer (score 1):

This is a really weird use-case for a mixin, but to you answer your question:

```
@mixin divTitles {
    &:lang(en):before {
        content: "My Title";
    }

    &:lang(es):before {
        content: "Mi título";
    }
}
```

I would suggest something this specific to just be a css selector.

```
.myDiv {
    &:lang(en):before {
        content: "My Title";
    }

    &:lang(es):before {
        content: "Mi título";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now, but I have two suggestions:

- remove the second "&": &:lang(en) and :before
- use [lang|=en] instead of lang(en)